# how to add a .hpp file in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am trying to add a Bitmap Library to visual studio 2015 when i added header file

```
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"
```

underneath the header file a red line  and
it showing "cannot open source file" in the error window i am attaching a link to website
i tried this way but its not help - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466571/add-hpp-file-type-to-visual-studio#

library link http://www.partow.net/programming/bitmap/index.html

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"

int main(){
    

bitmap_image image("input.bmp");

if (!image)
{
    printf("Error - Failed to open: input.bmp\n");
    return 1;
}

unsigned int total_number_of_pixels = 0;

const unsigned int height = image.height();
const unsigned int width = image.width();

for (std::size_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        rgb_t colour;

        image.get_pixel(x, y, colour);

        if (colour.red >= 111)
            total_number_of_pixels++;
    }
}

printf("Number of pixels with red >= 111: %d\n", total_number_of_pixels);

return 0;
}
```

header is too large i can't paste it here its in the link

Comment: You need to tell Visual Studio where to find the header file. You do that in your project properties.

Comment: The post you linked to seems to be for a completely different problem.

Comment: Set the "Additional Include Directories" setting for all configurations you use. You probably also will need to add linker settings to tell the linker what directory and what library to link to.

Comment: I don't have a copy of VS 2015 handy but in VS 2019 it's Project Properties/Configuration Properties/C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories. It's probably similar in your version.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code, or in the header, it's your project properties.

Comment: @john .now the red line is gone but i can't compile . error -> the system file cannot find the file specified

Comment: i added the folder of this file  bitmap_image.hpp

Comment: @user3861918 What's the exact error that you see? Cut and paste the exact error message

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C4996 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' Project1 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 2230

Comment: The warning / error message told you what to do. Just follow the instruction to disable the secure warnings.

Comment: That error would normally be a warning, so you must have the 'treat warnings as errors' option turned on. So you could turn that off, or you could do what the message says and add the preprocessing definition `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to your project properties.

Comment: You'll have to ask Microsoft that. They try to warn against what they think is risky code, even if according to C++ it's prefectly legal code.