# Why does Visual Studio 2019 create a .h file when I explicitly tell it to create a .hpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I want to add a new class to my project from solution explorer in Visual Studio 2019, I am presented with this window:

[image]

When I hit enter on my keyboard, MyClass.h is created, despite me explicitly telling it that I want a .hpp file.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious? Cuz when I use some other extension it won't let me to create the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add .hpp File Type to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466571/add-hpp-file-type-to-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm pretty sure VS is hardcoded to .h extension. Report it to Msft: *Help...* -> *Send Feedback...* -> *Report a Problem...*